# Distributions with finite number of moments

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions

Is it easy to provide an example of a distribution that has, say, finite moments of order one and two, but such that $\mathbb{E}[X^k]=\infty$ or does not exist for all $k>2$ (where $k$ is not necessarily an integer)?

More generally, is there a way to construct a distribution with an arbitrary number of moments, in the sense that $\mathbb{E}[X^k]$ converges for $k \leq b$ and diverges or is non-existent for $k>b$? To emphasize: $b, k$ are real.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using Fubini-Tonnelli's theorem, we have that for a non-negative random variable $X$ and a real number $r$, $$\mathbb E[X^r]=r\int_0^{\infty}t^{r-1}\mathbb P\{X\gt t\}\mathrm dt.$$

We thus consider $X$ such that its distribution function is such that for $t\geqslant 2$, 
$$\mathbb P\{X\gt t\}=\frac{C}{t^b(\log t)^2}$$
and $C=2^b(\log 2)^2$ in order to have $\mathbb P\{X\gt 2\}=1$.

Answer (score 2):

Yes. For any positive $b$, consider $X$ with the PDF $f$ defined by
$$
f(x)  = \begin{cases}
bx^{-1-b}&\text{ if $x>1$}
\\
0&\text{ otherwise}
\end{cases}
$$

Then $E[X^k]$ is finite if and only if $k<b$.

Comment: Thank you, but the trouble seems to be dealing with the $k=b$  situation, which is why the question is phrased as ''$\mathbb{E}[X^k]$ is finite if and only if $k \leq b$''.

Comment: @Guest a simple idea is to put a $\log$ in the denominator to make the integral converge.